# Istio OAuth2 with Keycloak

Tags: istio, api-gateway, envoyproxy

I am using Istio as API Gateway and Service Mesh. The plan is to have the authentication and authorization flow (oauth2) being managed by the Ingress Envoy Gateway in Istio. However, the usage of Envoy filters are not redirecting the URL request to the login page as expected (the example followed can be found in [here](https://medium.com/@suman_ganta/openid-authentication-with-istio-a32838adb492) and the login is not happening.
If I try to connect by curl (authenticate, use the token received to get the authorization), it works fine. But when involve the Oauth 2 flow, it gets stuck.
This authorizations are being done using **Keycloak**.

This is the Lua Filter being used:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: authn-filter
  namespace: istio-test
spec:
  filters:
  - filterConfig:
      inlineCode: |
        function login (request_handle)
          request_handle:logInfo("logging in")
          local request_url = "http://"..request_handle:headers():get(":authority")..request_handle:headers():get(":path")
          request_handle:logInfo(request_url)
          headers, body = request_handle:httpCall(
            "outbound|3000||service-gatekeeper.istio-test.svc.cluster.local",
            {
              [":method"] = "POST",
              [":path"] = "/oauth/authorize",
              [":authority"] = request_handle:headers():get(":authority"),
              ["X-Auth-Request-Redirect"] = request_url
            },
            nil,
            5000)
          return headers, body
        end
        function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
          local path = request_handle:headers():get(":path")
          -- ignore metrics, liveness probe requests
          request_handle:logInfo("Envoy on Request")
          if path == "/" then
            return
          end
          token = request_handle:headers():get("Authorization")
          cookie = request_handle:headers():get("Cookie")
          if token == nil and cookie == nil then
             request_handle:logInfo("about to login")
             headers, body = login(request_handle)
             request_handle:respond(headers,body)
          end
          request_handle:logInfo("validating token against Certs")
          local headers, body = request_handle:httpCall(
            "outbound|8080||eseabyr-oauth2-proxy-innulic-test.svc.cluster.local",
            {
              [":method"] = "GET",
              [":path"] = "/oauth/authorize",
              [":authority"] = request_handle:headers():get(":authority"),
              ["Authorization"] = token,
              ["Cookie"] = cookie
            },
            nil,
            5000)
          local status
          for header, value in pairs(headers) do
            if header == ":status" then
               status = value
            end
          end

          request_handle:logInfo("token validation status:"..status)
          if status == "401" then
            headers, body = login(request_handle)
            request_handle:respond(headers,body)
          end
        end
        -- Called on the response path.
        function envoy_on_response(response_handle)
            local headers = response_handle:headers()
            headers:add("X-Envoy-Ingress", os.getenv("HOSTNAME"))
        end
    filterName: envoy.lua
    filterType: HTTP
    listenerMatch:
      listenerType: GATEWAY
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you come any closer to the solution on this?

Comment: Unfortunately no :(

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have the full details of your environment, I can suggest the following as a way to debug the issue:

> 1. I see that you do not have workloadLabels, which means this filter should be attached to all pods in your mesh.
> 2. Make sure istio init containers are being injected to your pods (either using istioctl or using k8s admission controllers)
> 3. Check the logs of the sidecar proxy attached to the pod of your interest. I'm guessing there is some syntax error, which will disable
>      the filter altogether. Otherwise it should give you what is going
>      wrong with the filter.